# 3 level nested views combining Tab Navigation & Side Menu Navigation with Ionic Frameworks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, ionic-framework

I see many examples out there combining the tab navigation & side menu navigation together but they are not nested, or example with nested views on side menu navigation only, in my case, I'd like to implement a tab navigation inside one of the side menu navigation only, however, I've been trying for days but still cannot figure it out, here's my pen: http://codepen.io/auching/pen/vyzJg

```
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('eventmenu', {
      url: "/event",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "event-menu.html"
    })
    .state('eventmenu.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "home.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.checkin', {
      url: "/check-in",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "check-in.html",
          controller: "CheckinCtrl"
        }
      }
    })
  .state('eventmenu.checkin.home1', {
      url: "/home1",
      views: {
        'home1-tab' :{
          templateUrl: "home1.html",
        }
      }
    })
  .state('eventmenu.checkin.home2', {
      url: "/home2",
      views: {
        'home2-tab' :{
          templateUrl: "home2.html",
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.attendees', {
      url: "/attendees",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "attendees.html",
          controller: "AttendeesCtrl"
        }
      }
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/event/home");
})
```

any help would be much appreciated! thx.

Comment: What do you mean by `3 level nested view` is it something like each level has their own template and you want to load them ?

Comment: maybe "3 level nested states" sounds more properly, within one of the evenmenu, I also want a tab menu in it.  @Reza

Comment: what is the question? We don't know where you are having problems

Comment: I have also been struggling with this for hours.  No one seems to know how to do it.  I was able to get it somewhat working, but the lcoation bar was not being updated with the URL parameters when I switched views!

Comment: Refer to this - does it help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363426/ui-router-why-parent-states-must-be-abstract

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Ionic tabs on a side menu page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857221/using-ionic-tabs-on-a-side-menu-page)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at navtest. It's not a good starter, but it's an example of how to combine different navigational concepts in a way that works in Ionic. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tests