# Using Ionic tabs on a side menu page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am new to the ionic framework and was trying to achieve using the tabs component on a side menu page which works fine but the navigation animations from page to page with the slide-left-right animation declaration don't work.

for e.g. 
there is a base state (app) which holds the side menu code

```
.state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        controller: "appController"
    })
```

and its loaded into

```
<body>
    <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
...
```

side menu pages are loaded with the parent (app.pageOne, app.pageTwo etc)

Login and register pages are loaded at the root so is no need to include a side menu (login, register etc)

I created a tabs template to use on a side menu page with another base state for the tabs

```
.state('app.tabs', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
            }
        }
    })
```

and is loaded in the side menu view

```
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
```

Now if I have a page 'app.pageOne' and navigate to 'app.pageTwo' the slide animations works as expected.

But if I'm on a tab page 'app.tabs.home' and click a link to go to 'app.pageTwo' the nav-bar don't update nor is there any animation transition.

I'm aware it looks like a parent child issue but I just can't solve it, any ideas?

state are as follows eg

```
login
register
app ____page1
   |____page2
   |____Tabs
          |____Home
          |____Contact etc
```

page1 animation to page2 works fine
Home to page2 doesn't animate (It just loads straight away)

Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Wll, honestly the biggest problem here is in the unclear issue definition. You are showing different *states* declaration than is your issue driven by (what is app.tabs.home?). Please, show more. And even better, create a plunker. You'll get help then much more easier...

Comment: Thanks for your question, I have updated the question to explain the states better, cheers

Comment: if possible to please add your codepen..

Answer (score 5):

check this url http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/JdtuG?editors=101
it works for me :)

html

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Ionic Template</title>

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.27/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.27/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- ALL VIEW STATES LOADED IN HERE -->
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

<script id="entry.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-nav-bar animation="nav-title-slide-ios7"
                 type="bar-positive"
                 back-button-type="button-icon"
                 back-button-icon="ion-ios7-arrow-back">
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-view title="{{navTitle}}" class="bubble-background">

        <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">

            <h1>Entry Page!</h1>

            <a class="button button-positive" ng-click="signIn()" ui-sref="main.home">Sign In</a>

        </ion-content>

    </ion-view>

</script>

<script id="tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="{{navTitle}}"  left-buttons="leftButtons">

        <ion-tabs tabs-type="tabs-icon-only">
            <ion-tab title="Tab 1" icon-on="ion-ios7-filing" icon-off="ion-ios7-filing-outline">
                <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
                    <h2>Tab 1 Content</h2>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab title="Tab 2" icon-on="ion-ios7-filing" icon-off="ion-ios7-filing-outline">
                <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
                    <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab title="Tab 3" icon-on="ion-ios7-filing" icon-off="ion-ios7-filing-outline">
                <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
                    <h2>Tab 3 Content</h2>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>


    </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="mainContainer.html" type="text/ng-template">

    <ion-side-menus>

        <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar type="bar-positive"
                         back-button-type="button-icon"
                         back-button-icon="ion-ios7-arrow-back"
                         animation="nav-title-slide-ios7"
                >

             </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-view name="main"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-pane>

        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <header class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
                <div class="title">Side Menu</div>
            </header>
            <ion-content has-header="true">
                <ul class="list">
                    <a ui-sref="entry" class="item">Back To Entry Page</a>
                    <a ui-sref="main.home" class="item" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Home</a>
                    <a ui-sref="main.tabs" class="item" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Tabs</a>
                </ul>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>

    </ion-side-menus>


</script>


<script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="{{navTitle}}" left-buttons="leftButtons">

        <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">

            <h1>Home Page!</h1>

            <a ui-sref="main.info" class="button button-positive">Info</a>

        </ion-content>

    </ion-view>

</script>

<script id="info.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="{{navTitle}}" left-buttons="leftButtons">

        <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">

            <h1>Info Page!</h1>

        </ion-content>

    </ion-view>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('entry', {
                url : '/entry',
                templateUrl : 'entry.html',
                controller : 'EntryPageController'
            })

            .state('main', {
                url : '/main',
                templateUrl : 'mainContainer.html',
                abstract : true,
                controller : 'MainController'
            })

            .state('main.home', {
                url: '/home',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                        templateUrl: 'home.html',
                        controller : 'HomePageController'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('main.info', {
                url: '/info',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                        templateUrl: 'info.html',
                        controller : 'InfoPageController'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('main.tabs', {
                 url: '/tabs',
                 views: {
                     'main': {
                         templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
                         controller : 'TabsPageController'
                     }
                 }
            })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/entry');
    }])

    .controller('MainController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.toggleMenu = function() {
            $scope.sideMenuController.toggleLeft();
        }
    }])

    .controller('EntryPageController', [ '$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Entry Page';

        $scope.signIn = function() {
            $state.go('main.home');
        }
    }])

    .controller('HomePageController', [ '$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Home Page';

        $scope.leftButtons = [{
            type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
            tap: function(e) {
                $scope.toggleMenu();
            }
        }];
    }])

    .controller('InfoPageController', [ '$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Info Page';

        $scope.leftButtons = [{
            type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
            tap: function(e) {
                $scope.toggleMenu();
            }
        }];
    }])

    .controller('TabsPageController', [ '$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Tab Page';

        $scope.leftButtons = [{
            type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
            tap: function(e) {
                $scope.toggleMenu();
            }
        }];
    }])
```

it took some tweaks but finally worked on my scenario