# How to use tabs and slide menu together on ionic framework latest beta 14?

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I was looking for examples of ionic apps which uses tabs and slide menu both. Yes i came across few examples but most of them are outdated and not working with latest beta.

For example this one:

http://tinyurl.com/sflowmotto1

It's working with 14 beta but there is a problem. My customer doesn't want sliding bottom tabs.

And this one is working great with 0.9.26 but not 14:

http://tinyurl.com/sflowmotto2

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
```

```
<title>Tabs and Slide-out menu Example</title>

<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.26/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.26/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</div>

<script id="menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-side-menus>
    <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
         <ion-nav-bar animation="nav-title-slide-ios7" 
         type="bar-positive" 
         left-buttons="leftButtons"
         back-button-type="button-icon" 
         back-button-icon="ion-arrow-left-c"></ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-nav-view name="menu-content"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane> 
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
      <ion-content>
        <ul class="list">
          <a href="#/main/tab/home" class="item" ng-click="mainCtrl.showFeature = false">Home</a>
          <a href="#/main/tab/about" class="item"ng-click="mainCtrl.showFeature = false">About</a>
          <a href="#/main/tab/contact" class="item"ng-click="mainCtrl.showFeature = fakse">Contact</a>
          <a href="#/main/tab/feature" class="item" ng-click="mainCtrl.showFeature = true">Feature</a>
        </ul>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>    
</script>

<script id="tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-tabs tabs-style="tabs-icon-top" tabs-type="tabs-positive">

    <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/main/tab/home">
      <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios7-information" href="#/main/tab/about">
      <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios7-world" ui-sref="main.tabs.contact">
      <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Feature" icon="ion-ios7-world" ui-sref="main.tabs.feature" ng-if="mainCtrl.showFeature">
      <ion-nav-view name="feature-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
</script>

<script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="'Home'" left-buttons="leftButtons">
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true" >
      <p>Example of Ionic tabs. Navigate to each tab, and
      navigate to child views of each tab and notice how
      each tab has its own navigation history.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/main/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
      <p>This next button navigates to a view that does not have a tab or present
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="facts.html" type="text/ng-template" >
  <ion-view title="'Facts'" left-buttons="leftButtons">
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
      <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
      <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
      <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
      <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
      <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/main/tab/home"> Home</a>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/main/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="facts2.html" type="text/ng-template" >
  <ion-view title="'Also Factual'" left-buttons="leftButtons">
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
      <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
      <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
      <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
      <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
      <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
      <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/main/tab/home"> Home</a>
        <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/main/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="about.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="'About'" left-buttons="leftButtons">
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
      <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
      <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
      <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/main/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="'Tab Nav Stack'" left-buttons="leftButtons">
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
      <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="contact.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="'Contact'" left-buttons="leftButtons">
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
      <p>@IonicFramework</p>
      <p>@DriftyCo</p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="feature.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="'Feature'" left-buttons="leftButtons">
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
      This is a feature pane that does not require a visible tab button.
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

```
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}


angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    .state('main', {
      url: "/main",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "menu.html"
    })

    .state('main.tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      views: {
        'menu-content': {
          templateUrl: "tabs.html",
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.tabs.facts', {
      url: "/facts",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "facts.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.tabs.facts2', {
      url: "/facts2",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "facts2.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.tabs.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "about.html"
        }
      }
    })

    .state('main.tabs.feature', {
      url: "/feature",
      views: {
        'feature-tab': {
          templateUrl: "feature.html"
        }
      }
    })

  .state('main.tabs.navstack', {
      url: "/navstack",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "nav-stack.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.tabs.contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: "contact.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.feature', {
      url: "/feature",
      views: {
        'menu-content': {
          templateUrl: "feature.html"
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main/tab/home");

})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

  $scope.mainCtrl = {};
  $scope.leftButtons = [{
    type: 'button-icon button-clear ion-navicon',
    tap: function(e) {
      $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft($scope.$$childHead);
    }
  }];

  $scope.mainCtrl.showFeature = false;

});
```

I am pretty curios why the second example doesn't work with beta 14 ?

here is the link of broken version some icons and animations are missing:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNMNQb

edit: the question is different from previous questions due to new changes on new version.

Comment: It looks like your first two links are broken. Can you update them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Ionic tabs on a side menu page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857221/using-ionic-tabs-on-a-side-menu-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the beta 14 https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/releases

> Breaking Changes:
>
> Animation CSS: The CSS for view transitions have changed. This is a
>   breaking change only if Ionic apps had customized Ionic’s animation
>   CSS. Additionally, all keyframe animations were removed since they
>   weren't being used. (20Kb saved!)

This code for example is deprecated:

```
<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
```

i'm still looking for a solution, i've been searching for 10hrs now, i want my tabs to animate :'(

Comment: Were you able to find any solution?