# How to set up sidemenu with tabs in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my opinion having a sidemenu, for things like settings and about pages, combined with tabs for the main app is a pretty essential and standard app interface. Things like Google's Messenger app use this.

I'm struggling to get it working and I see there are a lot of questions about it with very little satisfactory information. I've combined a sidemenu with swipeboxes fine. This should be just as easy. I used to use jQuery Mobile for my apps, which is much more clunky than Ionic but doing an interface like this is easy and it works well.

The problem I'm having is the tab templates don't load into the tabs. This may be something silly I'm missing but here is my app.js code snippet:

```
config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.tabs', {
    url: "/tabs",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
      }
    }
  })

.state('tab.tab1', {
      url: 'tab/tab1',
      views: {
        'tab-tab1': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-tab1.html',
          controller: 'tab1Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })

.state('tab.tab-tab2', {
      url: 'tab/tab2',
      views: {
        'tab-tab2': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-tab2.html',
          controller: 'tab2Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })

.state('tab.extras', {
    url: 'tab/extras',
    views: {
      'tab-extras': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-extras.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

    .state('app.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/about.html",
          controller: 'aboutCtrl'
        }
      }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/tabs');
});
```

The side menu works fine and I can navigate with it to the about page or back to the tabs. The tabs work in that they change focus and the icons change colour, but the templates don't load into them. I've tripple double checked the url names.

Does anyone know how to do this? If I've made a small error somewhere and get it working I'll Codepen this as an example of how to create this, imho, much needed interface.

Edit: As requested.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-assertive">  

  <ion-tab title="tab1" icon="ion-man" href="#/tab/tab1">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-tab1"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="tab2" icon="ion-person-stalker" href="#/tab/tab2">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-tab2"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Extras" icon="ion-heart" href="#/tab/extras">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-extras"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

I think they all match up, no?

Note - with regards to the query about this being a duplicate; my app is a tabbed app with a side menu on the base page. The other question is about an app with a series of sections, one of which has tabs. It's a different structure altogether.

Comment: Most likely problem is that the `name`s of the `<ion-nav-view>`s in your **tabs.html** don't match those in the `views` object for that state. Can you post **tabs.html**? There's a good Codepen on Ionic site http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz

Comment: I've added it. Ha ha. Just seen who this is.

Comment: I've noticed you don't have an abstract `tab` state to nest things under. They might not get registered as child states if there is no proper parent.

Comment: Yeah, that might be it. I don't know how to get around it though. I can't have two abstract views.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Ionic tabs on a side menu page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857221/using-ionic-tabs-on-a-side-menu-page)

Comment: My app has a totally different structure. It's a tabbed app - tabs for the sections - with a side menu for settings and so on. The other question is about a side menu app that has one section that is tabbed. Quite different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your routing is a bit off - your child states for the tabs aren't fully declared. You've declared them like this

```
.state('tab.tab1', {
```

...and you've never declared the parent `tab` state. So they are left 'hanging' until the parent state is declared. ui-router will just ignore them until this happens.

Try this

```
config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.tabs', {
    url: "/tabs",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
      }
    }
  })

.state('app.tabs.tab1', {
      url: '/tab1',
      views: {
        'tab-tab1': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-tab1.html',
          controller: 'tab1Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })

.state('app.tabs.tab2', {
      url: '/tab2',
      views: {
        'tab-tab2': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-tab2.html',
          controller: 'tab2Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })

.state('app.tabs.extras', {
    url: '/extras',
    views: {
      'tab-extras': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-extras.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

    .state('app.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/about.html",
          controller: 'aboutCtrl'
        }
      }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/tabs');
});
```

And better / clearer to use `ui-sref` rather than `href` in your tabs template - easier to see what state something maps to

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-assertive">  

  <ion-tab title="tab1" icon="ion-man" ui-sref="app.tabs.tab1">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-tab1"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="tab2" icon="ion-person-stalker" ui-sref="app.tabs.tab2">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-tab2"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Extras" icon="ion-heart" ui-sref="app.tabs.extras">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-extras"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Not tested it but I think that should fix it! Any errors in the console BTW?

Comment: No errors in the console. I've tried app.tabs.tab1 and it doesn't work either.

Comment: This is the answer. It's the ui-sref that did it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having an issue with the links in the side menu to the app.tabs view. it seems like the router does not work, you have an example with links at the side bar menu?

Comment: Are you using with Ionic 1 or 2?